# How to affect only other links when one is being hovered

Tags: css

I've been trying to make all other links shrink when one is being hovered, but so far it only shrinks the links afterwards the one being hovered

```css
.navlink {
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.navlink:hover~.navlink {
  width: 50px;
}

.navlink:hover {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a class="navlink">link 1</a>
<a class="navlink">link 2</a>
<a class="navlink">link 3</a>
<a class="navlink">link 4</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try flexbox for this and you only need to adjust the hovered link and the other will shrink by default

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.navlink {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.navlink:hover {
  flex: 3; /*Adjust this to control the size*/
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="navlink">link 1</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 2</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 3</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good for modern browsers, but for support of older browsers is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making the width of the resize to be equal to that which it started. If you have four elements at `100px` starting, which will make the total width `400px` (plus any margin/padding stuff), then make the resized elements equal out to `400px` as well to ensure that you are not getting any weird stuff.

```css
.navlink {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.container:hover .navlink:not(:hover) {
  width: 75px;
}

.navlink:hover {
  width: 175px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="navlink">link 1</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 2</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 3</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this html code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <a class="navlink">link 1</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 2</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 3</a>
  <a class="navlink">link 4</a>
</div>
```

y css:

```
.navlink {
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
.parent:hover .navlink{
  width:50px;
}
.parent .navlink:hover{
  width:150px;
  background-color:pink;
}
```